# Decision Rule for Random-Walk Metropolis on Log Scale

Tags: bayesian, logarithm, metropolis-hastings

I need to sample from a non-standard density which is more tractable on the log-scale. Now I was wondering, how the decision rule is restated:
$$ \alpha (x' | x ) = min(1,\frac{\pi(x')}{\pi(x)}) $$ with $x'$ being a candidate draw from a symmetric proposal distribution.

Is it correct to infer the following decision rule:
$$ \tilde{\alpha} = log(\alpha(x'|x)) = min(0, log(\pi(x')) - log(\pi(x)))$$ Accept Draw $x'$ if $\tilde{\alpha} \geq log(u)$ with $u\sim\mathcal{U}(0,1)$

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is correct.

Also it is not necessary to actually compute the minimum, i.e. you can accept if 
$$ \log(u) \le \log(\pi(x')) - \log(\pi(x)). $$

In addition, you can avoid drawing the uniform and computing its log any time that 
$$ \log(\pi(x')) \ge \log(\pi(x))$$
since $\log(u)$ is always less than the difference $\log(\pi(x')) - \log(\pi(x))$.

Comment: Does that mean I accept the draw if $log(\pi(x')) \geq log(\pi(x))$ ?